# scraping coordinates from tweets using python

Tags: python, twitter, coordinates

I'm trying to scrape Twitter with python for tweets that mention @HillaryClinton and pull the coordinates of the tweets to create a map. I'm a new new python user and this is really killing me. I've pulled a list of tweets into a text file already and here is the code I came up with to pull the coordinates. However I get the error: 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Can't figure this out.

```
inFile = open('C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python Scripts\Clinton.txt', 'r')
rawJson = inFile.read()
Clinton_results = json.loads(rawJson)

for status in Clinton_results:
    if 'coordinates' in status:
    print (status['place']['bounding_box']['coordinates'])
```

Comment: You check `if 'coordinates in status`, which only means that `status['coordinates']` exists.  It says nothing about `status['place']['bounding_box']['coordinates']`.

Comment: hilarious things.